# Microsoft Report Designer: Undocumented Error

Tags: asp.net, dataset, reporting, rdlc

I am working with asp.net reporting using RDLC file. Everything was working fine but now when I add a new dataset, an error occurs.

[image]

I have no more info than this, to provide you people to diagnose the problem. Have anyone idea what would be happening?

I just want to add a new dataset.

Comment: From the name "PrecisionCareEntity" I guess you're using the entity framework and you have an entity called PrecisionCare, is that correct?

Comment: no no.// I am not using entityframework. I have just assigned a name entity. and it is a project. I tried to make it like entity framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by following this method:

1. Add a datasource in your report viewer i.e. in aspx page.
2. Go to its designer and click on the arrow appearing in front of datasource, and click on it.
3. Click Refresh Scehma and Save the file.
4. Go to its code again and comment the datasource code.
5. Try adding new dataset in rdlc. It will allow adding new datasets now.

Comment: I added some code after step 1 that is not appearing here. Here is that code: `<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsAdmission" runat="server" 
            OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
            SelectMethod="SelectAdmissionForReport" 
            TypeName="PrecisionCareBLL.AdmissionBLL.AdmissionLogic">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="admissionId" QueryStringField="Id" 
                    Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>`

Answer (score 0):

You referenced a Library that you created called 'PrecisionCareEntity', did you? So just remove the reference and redo it.

Overall I would suggest using Visual Studio 2008/2010 with Reporting Services Integration installed. With that you get MUCH better results and less Errors!

e: In Visual Studio:

Top Menu -> Report -> Report Properties... -> References:

- Select the Reference
- Click on Delete

Comment: I am using VS10 reporting. and this is not my project. I have just to create a report. I didn't create any library. What should I do?

Comment: sorry, but i am finding Report nowhere in my top menu.

Comment: on the right side (usually) you have your solution explorer, look for something like your "PrecisionCareEntity" in the "References" Folder under your project. Cut it out and try again to add a dataset. Did this work before? Have you changed anything since then?

Comment: I haven't changed anything like this ever before.